mypy and python type hinting: How do I specify type A from A|B at run time?
I need some help with the mypy type-checking for Python. I have a provided function whose output type depends on a runtime argument. I am setting that argument so that I know the type of output. How do I persuade mypy that of the A|B type choice it is going to be type A?
Specifically, I am using the ollama API which has a client method as follows. (I am quoting from the built-in help docs.)
def generate(
    model: str = '',
    prompt: str = '',
    stream: bool = False
) -> Union[Mapping[str, Any], collections.abc.Iterator[Mapping[str, Any]]]
    """
    Create a response using the requested model.

    Raises `RequestError` if a model is not provided.
    Raises `ResponseError` if the request could not be fulfilled.

    Returns `GenerateResponse` if `stream` is `False`,
    otherwise returns a `GenerateResponse` generator.
    """

I am setting the stream argument to be False (as a literal in the code, not as the result of logic) and I want to let mypy know that I am certain I am receiving a GenerateResponse rather than a GenerateResponse generator.
I can use # type: ignore to disable all type checking, but I would like to know if there is something less dramatic I can do in my code. (I cannot change the ollama module code.)
At the moment I am using type: ignore to turn off all type checking. This works, but feels like a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

"I cannot change the ollama module code." - good news. The necessary changes have been made on the master branch, so this should be fixed in 0.2.2.

This kind of Boolean parameter is an antipattern. Define two functions, and use the Boolean value to select which function to call instead. (Or, always return a generator, and let the caller use next to extract the only expected value.)
